# jQuery sliders and changing div container content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, here is what i got so far:

first, go here to see what i am trying to describe:
http://pcnow.org/testing/

What i want to do is this:
Somebody goes to the website above, and wants to know what kind of sandwich they can make using what they have in their kitchen. So from the example above they will select the number of slices of bread they have, select the number of slices of lunch meat they have, and click the submit button.

What makes this tricky, at least for me, is that i want it to be random, and that is where i am running into a roadblock. I don't want the same user to get the same sandwich over and over, because even though they might have the same ingredients, they might want a new choice of end product. So when they select how many slices of bread and lunch meat they have, instead of the "content" container saying "initial page load content would go here.." it would say something like "with those ingredients, you can make this sandwich, and this sandwich"

So after all that rambling, is this even possible?

I cannot for the life of me figure out to paste code into this place, it is tricky, sorry for that as well.

Comment: You are mentioning several problems. 1) you want different combinations for each request to the page. Should it be totally random? 2) You want to tell user which choice of combination he has. Am I right? For the second part you need to have your own algorithm right? Or you just wanna read the numbers that users have selected? Clear it out first.

Comment: @Ambodi 1. Yes I would like it to be random if at all possible, so each user would be presented with a different sandwich.

As for the second part of your question, I don't know yet, Don't know which would work best, new to coding so don't know yet which is gonna be easiest to implement. I guess it would be easier to just read the number that they select on the sliders and have that pull different combinations from somewhere. If that is even possible.

Comment: @Ambodi Basically something like this: http://whatwillilooklike.com/ , but instead of show images, i want it to show different recipes based on the slider criteria.

Comment: Wrote my answer for you. hope it works out

Answer (score 0):

OK, I wrote a code example for you to see and see if that works for you.

I have used a JqueryUI Slider component which accepts a range and randomly every time a user comes to the page will select a range for him. Try run the example several times to see that the values almost never happens.

Firstly, generate random numbers for ranges:

```
var minVal = 100;
var maxVal = 1000;
var randomMin = Math.random() * 400 + minVal;
var randomMax = Math.random()*400 + (maxVal - minVal);
```

Then write the slider change event listener:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: minVal,
      max: maxVal,
      values: [randomMin, randomMax],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Here is the full URL for sample: [jQUery UI Slider with Random Range Values](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6EgB/)